# Classification output in random forest with randomForest package

Tags: r, random-forest

I've like to create a classification output using predict () function in random forest
for my code below:

```
#Packages
library(randomForest)
library(dplyr)

#Data
data(iris)
Rep<-seq(1,length(iris[,1]))
all_iris<-cbind(Rep,iris)


#Tranning RF
dg_o_cal<-all_iris %>% sample_n(150*0.8)
iris.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length 
+ Petal.Width, data=dg_o_cal, importance=TRUE, proximity=TRUE)

# Predicting on Validation set 
dg_s_val<-anti_join(all_iris,dg_o_cal, by=c("Rep"))
predValid <- predict(iris.rf, dg_s_val, type = "class")
# Checking classification accuracy
mean(predValid == dg_s_val$Species)                    
table(predValid,dg_s_val$Species)
#
```

But I've like an output in data frame format in dg_s_val object with a new column with RF classification (CLASS_RF) with the predicting on validation set  results like:

```
  Rep Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species CLASS_RF
1   6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa setosa
2   9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa virginica
3  10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa virginica
4  11          5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2  setosa setosa
5  15          5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2  setosa setosa
6  20          5.1         3.8          1.5         0.3  setosa setosa
...
```

Is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
dg_s_val$CLASS_RF <- predValid
```

You are assigning the list `predValid` to a column in `dg_s_val`